# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X}fd\mu_n = \int_Xfd\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Given is a a $\sigma$ - Algebra $\mathcal{A}$, a measure space $(X, \mathcal{A})$ and a sequence of measures $\left(\mu_n :\mathcal{A} \to [0,\infty]\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $\mu_n(A) \leq \mu_{n+1}(A)\:\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$. I have to show that if $f:X\to[0,\infty]$ is measureable with respect to $\mathcal{A}$, it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{X}fd\mu_n = \int_Xfd\mu$, where $\mu: \mathcal{A}\to[0,\infty]$, $\mu(A):=\sup\{\mu_n(A):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $A\in\mathcal{A}$. We have defind integrals with step functions, hence $f=\sum_{k=1}^N\alpha_k1_{A_k}$ and it follows by definition that $\int_Xfd\mu=\sum_{k=1}^N\alpha_k\mu(A_k)$ for an arbitrary measure $\mu$. I have literally no idea where to start...

Comment: First prove the case where $f$ is a step function. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints.

1. First [it is not clear that $\mu$ is indeed a measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042314/if-mu-n1e-ge-mu-ne-and-define-mu-e-lim-n-rightarrow-infty?rq=1).
2. Show that the sequence $\left( \int_{X}fd\mu_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is non-decreasing.
3. As a consequence, $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{X}fd\mu_n=\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\int_{X}fd\mu_n$.
4. By definition of the Lebesgue integral, $$\int_{X}fd\mu_n=\sup_{s\in\mathcal S} \int_{X}sd\mu_n ,$$
   where $\mathcal S=\left\{s\mid 0\leqslant s\leqslant f, .s=\sum_{i=1}^Nc_i\mathbf 1_{A_i},A_i\in\mathcal A\right\}$.  Switching the two supremum reduces to establish the result when $f=\sum_{i=1}^Nc_i\mathbf 1_{A_i},A_i\in\mathcal A$. Indeed, by 3. 
   $$
   \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{X}fd\mu_n=\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\sup_{s\in\mathcal S}\int_{X}sd\mu_n=\sup_{s\in\mathcal S}\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\int_{X}sd\mu_n.
   $$
   If we manage to show that for each $s\in\mathcal S$, the equality $\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\int_{X}sd\mu_n=\int_{X}sd\mu$, then we are done.
5. By linearity it suffices to do it when $f =\mathbf 1_{A},A\in\mathcal A$.

Comment: Thanks! However, we defined Lebesgue integral as $\int_xfd\mu_n=sup\{\int_xs_kd\mu_n, k\in\mathbb{N}\}$, where $s_k$ denotes a sequence of step funktions as defined by you. What am I missing?

Comment: I guess that in your definition, we have $s_k(x)\uparrow f(x)$ for all $x$. Ten the two definition are equivalent.

Comment: Alright. To show part 2.), I have to show that (using my definition) $sup\{\int_xs_kd\mu_n, k\in\mathbb{N}\} \leq sup\{\int_xs_kd\mu_{n+1}, k\in\mathbb{N}\}$. I can now drop the two suprema (right?), and after writing out the integral for a step function $s_k$ i get $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\alpha_i\mu_n(A_i)\leq\sum_{i=1}^\infty\alpha_i\mu_{n+1}(A_i)$, which is true due to my initial conditions.

Comment: And one more (hopefully) last question? Why does switching the suprema reduce the case to f being a step function? I then have something like $sup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left(sup_{n\geq1}\{\int_Xs_kd\mu_n\}\right)$, and I do not see how that leads me further...

Comment: Regard your first comment, yes. The only thing you have to modify is the index of the sum (the $\infty$ should be $N$). For your second comment, see the edit.

Comment: But what happens to the Index k in $s_k$? If I drop the supremum, can I drop the condition $k\in\mathbb{N}$?